T Pose between animations in React Three Fibre
I am using 3d models from Ready Player me and animations from Mixamo, when I switch between animations, I want a smooth transition but instead I get a T-pose between animations. The 3d models are glb files, I exported them to blender and got fbx files that I gave to mixamo and downloaded the animations from there. Here is my code :
  useEffect(() => {

    Object.keys(animationTriggers).forEach((key) => {
      if (animationTriggers[key] && actions[key]) {
        const action = actions[key];
        if (action) {
        Object.keys(actions).forEach((otherKey) => {
          if (otherKey !== key && actions[otherKey] && actions[otherKey].isRunning()) {
            actions[otherKey].fadeOut(0.5);
          }
        });

        // Fade in the new action
        action.reset().fadeIn(1).play();

        // Cleanup function to fade out the action when it stops
        return () => {
          action.fadeOut(1).play();
        };
        }

        console.log(`Playing animation: ${key}`);
      }
    });
  }, [animationTriggers, actions, mixer]);

var defaultAnimation = { greeting: false,talking3:false, idle: false, greeting2: false, looking:false, talking:false, walking: false, nod:false};
const triggerAnimation = (animation) => {

  const tempAnimations = { ...animations, [animation]: true };
  setAnimations(tempAnimations);
};


